# dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social

Tags: xcode, execution, dyld

I have the following execution problem when the application is runing on simulator:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
Referenced from: /Users/Development1/Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator/4.3.2/Applications/730C5B6A-130C-471D-B8C8-CE119B06ACF5/Emisora Atlantico.app/Emisora Atlantico
Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a clean build? How did you add the framework?

Answer (score 8):

The `Social` framework was added in iOS 6.0. You can't use it under iOS 4.3 or 5.x. You need proper runtime checks to ensure that you make no attempt to access any of the classes from the framework when you run on a device (or simulator) with iOS prior to 6.0.

You also need to weak link the Social framework to your project.

See the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i) for complete details on performing proper runtime checks.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the [answer provided by rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156802/377384), a quick solution may be changing the library from **Required** to **Optional** in the **Build Phases** tab of the Target Settings in XCode.

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 11 + CryptoKit**

I had the same issue here with the new `CryptKit` Framework which is available with iOS 13. In my case I needed to weak link the entire framework as described here to solve the issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html