# ShareKit Social.framework issue

Tags: ios, sharekit, social-framework

I want to use ShareKit but I got this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/867AE369-20D1-4F43-B4CF-859E0E0C3992/Quiz.app/Quiz
  Reason: image not found
```

The reason is in iOS version and `Social.framework`.

Can I use ShareKit in iOS 5.1?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156091/dyld-library-not-loaded-system-library-frameworks-social-framework-social

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Make social.framework optional, as stated in [ShareKit wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit).

Comment: I also made Account.framework and AdSupport.framework as optional and it works. thanks.